# Request cypher neo4j help regex number dollar

Tags: neo4j, request, cypher

I'd like to prefix numbers in a STRING field with a dollar between. My prefix here would be "TEST-".

Maybe a regex could help or any function ideas...?

Example of field content to the prefix:

```
match (u:User) return u;
```

`u.extId = 8046$015684`   -> this field is a string with numbers and $ in between

I d like to change it to `extId = TEST-8046$TEST-015684`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this simple string **concatenation** and **replace** will do the job.
The following query will change the field in the database if you don't want to change in the database and just want to return the new value, modify the query to return instead of SET.

```
MATCH (u:User)
SET u.extId = 'TEST-'+replace(u.extId, "$", "$TEST-")
```